# Extending a Model in Phalcon

Tags: php, phalcon

How would one make a child-parent relationship between Phalcon MVC models?

This is a DB schema I have in mind:

```
explain show;
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id      | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| length  | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| title   | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

explain show_episode;
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| show_id | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| season  | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| episode | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Each element in `show_episode` is also present in `show` table, however there are show records which are only present in `show`.

The idea is to have two Phalcon Model classes:

```
class Show extends Phalcon\Mvc\Model
{
  public $id;
  public $length;
  public $title;
}

class ShowEpisode extends Show 
{
  public $season;
  public $episode;
}
```

How would I need to configure those models to be able to retrieve and save episode records like this:

```
// retrieve
$episode = ShowEpisode::findFirst(array("id"=>333));
echo $episode->season;
echo $episode->title;

// save
$episode->title = "New Title";
$episode->season = 3;
$episode->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at;

```
class Show extends Phalcon\Mvc\Model
{
  public $id;
  public $length;
  public $title;

  public function initialize()
  {
    $this->hasMany("id", "Episode", "showid", NULL);
  }
}
```

Or something similar?

Comment: Hi Danny, thanks for the answer. I did indeed, however this only defines a relationship. You still need to create two different models (Show and ShowEpisode) each time you want to insert new record. Things get even more complicated when you try to update it.

Comment: I'll dig into it a bit as I have models that look and behave similar to yours.